# What is a child process? And how do I start it? (Linux, C)

Tags: c, linux, process, pid, child-process

I'm not familiar with C at all.

How do I start a child process? This child process is going to execute the specified command with a call to `execve()`. It will try to search among the file directory specified in the environment variable `PATH` after the command can be
found as executable file.

I've done this so far:

```
//Do commands 
pid_t childId;

// Fork the child process
child_id = safefork.c(); //can't use fork();
```

---

#### `safefork.c`

Code provided by the tutor; do not damn the messenger!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
extern int errno;
#define MAX_PROCESSES 6
static int n_processes(void)
{
    return system("exit `/bin/ps | /store/bin/wc -l`")/256;
}
pid_t safefork(void)
{
    static int n_initial = -1;
    if (n_initial == -1) /* Første gang funksjonen kalles: */
        n_initial = n_processes();
    else if (n_processes() >= n_initial+MAX_PROCESSES) {
        sleep(2);
        errno = EAGAIN;
        return (pid_t)-1;
    }
    return fork();
}
```

Comment: cant use fork why?? i dont think there is another way to fork a child process besides `fork()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. The notation `safefork.c()` is not usual in C; I could devise a structure type that would make it work, but it probably isn't what you meant. What do you mean by "can't use `fork()`"?  The main alternative mechanism is `vfork()`, which is a very restricted variant of `fork()` (do not use it); or maybe you could use `posix_spawn()` or `posix_spawnp()` - which are incredibly complex alternatives. I don't think there are any other options. After forking, you can use `execvp()` instead of `execve()` - it will do the path search for you.

Comment: we got another file called safefork :) we are not allowed to use fork, only safefork which is already given

Comment: OK; that's very curious.  Presumably, you got a header `safefork.h` which declares whatever function you're supposed to use (perhaps `extern int safefork(void);`), and the file `safefork.c` which does something to wrap around `fork()` or whatever.  'Tis odd: I don't think `fork()` is a dangerous function. I'd be curious to see what the 'safe fork' does, but I'm sceptical that it is significantly safer than the standard fork function.  (I suppose it could does some things like `fflush(0)` before invoking `fork()`, or do an error exit if the `fork()` fails, but that's pushing the envelope.)

Comment: The code for 'safefork()` is an abomination.  It runs a shell which runs `ps` and `wc` to find out how many processes you currently have running, and goes to sleep for 2 seconds if you can't do the `fork()` because there are too many (more than 6, including the 3 that the `safefork()` is running!) and then returns "I failed".  Someone needs their head seeing to (and no, that isn't you; it is the author of the code).  Oh, and `extern int errno;` is incorrect; the only safe way to declare `errno` is by `#include <errno.h>`.  Negative marks to the teacher for that blunder.

Comment: In your code, get the name of the variable spelled consistently.  `pid_t child_id = simplefork(); if (child_id < 0) { ...handle error... } else if (child_id == 0) { ...do childish code - execve() etc... } else { ...do parental code - waitpid() etc... }`.  (More negatives on the `safefork.c` code: `#include <sys/errno.h>` is not needed or a good idea; `#include <sys/types.h>` is not needed in modern POSIX -- from POSIX 2008 onwards at any rate; it may have been unnecessary before that).

Comment: I'm so sorry but I didnt get any of this, I just need to know how to start a child process

Comment: As I showed you: `pid_t child_id = simplefork();`.  If the value in `child_id` is 0, then you are in the child process; otherwise, you're in the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Fixing your code

In your code, get the name of the variable spelled consistently (`child_id` is not the same as `childId`).

```
pid_t child_id = simplefork();
if (child_id < 0)
{
    ...handle error...
}
else if (child_id == 0)
{
    ...do childish code - execve() etc...
}
else
{
    ...do parental code - waitpid() etc...
}
```

Note that the `fork()` call within the `simplefork()` function that you're given to use is responsible for creating the new process.  That's all it takes; that's the way it's done for all processes except the very first process.

---

#### Why not `fork()`?

What do you mean by "can't use [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html)"? The main alternative mechanism is [`vfork()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/vfork), which is a very restricted variant of `fork()` (do not use it); or maybe you could use [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html) or `posix_spawnp()` — which are incredibly complex alternatives. I don't think there are any other options.

After forking, you might be able to use [`execvp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) instead of [`execve()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html) — it will do the path search for you.  Unless, of course, the purpose of the exercise is to implement `execvp()` in terms of `execve()`.

Your code uses the notation `safefork.c()`, but that is not usually correct in C; I could devise a structure type that would make it work, but it probably isn't what you meant.

> We got another file called `safefork.c` — we are not allowed to use `fork`, only `safefork` which is already given.

<sup>*[…before the code was posted]*</sup>

OK; that's very curious. Presumably, you got a header `safefork.h` which declares whatever function you're supposed to use (perhaps `extern pid_t safefork(void);`), and the file `safefork.c` which does something to wrap around `fork()`. 'Tis odd: I don't think fork() is a dangerous function. I'd be curious to see what the 'safe fork' does, but I'm sceptical that it is significantly safer than the standard fork function. (I suppose it could does some things like fflush(0) before invoking fork(), or do an error exit if the fork() fails, but that's pushing the envelope.)

<sup>*[…after the code was posted]*</sup>

*A critique of the code for `safefork()`, which I fully recognize is not your own code but code that is given to you to use.*

The code for `safefork()` is an abomination. It runs a shell via `system()` which runs `ps` and `wc` to find out how many processes you currently have running, and goes to sleep for 2 seconds if you can't do the `fork()` because there are too many processes running (more than 6, maybe including the 3 that the `safefork()` is running!) and then returns "I failed". Someone needs their head seeing to (and no, that isn't you; it is the author of the code).

Oh, and `extern int errno;` is incorrect; the only safe way to declare `errno` is by `#include <errno.h>`. Negative marks to the teacher for that blunder. It is not a good idea to `#include <sys/errno.h>`; `#include <sys/types.h>` is not often needed in modern POSIX — from POSIX 2008 onwards at any rate; it may have been unnecessary before that).  In the context of the `safefork.h` header, making it self-contained does require `#include <sys/types.h>`.

Even assuming that `safefork()` is a good idea (it isn't), it should be implemented as shown below.

#### `safefork.h`

```
#ifndef SAFEFORK_H_INCLUDED
#define SAFEFORK_H_INCLUDED

#include <sys/types.h>   // pid_t
extern pid_t safefork(void);

#endif
```

#### `safefork.c`

```
#include "safefork.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_PROCESSES 6

static int n_processes(void)
{
    return system("exit `/bin/ps | /store/bin/wc -l`") / 256;
}

pid_t safefork(void)
{
    static int n_initial = -1;
    if (n_initial == -1)
        n_initial = n_processes();
    else if (n_processes() >= n_initial+MAX_PROCESSES)
    {
        errno = EAGAIN;
        return (pid_t)-1;
    }
    return fork();
}
```

Comment: This is a university assignment, where safefork is given as attachment. We have to replace fork with safefork, so processes should not run wild - and also we HAVE to use execv

Comment: OK; I've modified the answer to make its structure clearer.  The first section is about how to fix/write your code.  The remainder is a deconstruction of the `simplefork()` code.  You can ignore the remainder; the first section contains the information you need to use.